# Move scene objects according to camera path

Tags: animation, camera, path

So i have been trying a bit to hard to figure this one out.

**I want to be able to move all objects of a scene in a way that imitates a camera path.**

Here is a simple scene i created for testing.

[image]

In this setup i have the camera animated along the path.

**What i would like is to have the camera stay at the world origin and move the world objects around to simulate the same effect as the camera path.**

I tried a bunch of null object parenting but i cannot get anything to look right.

Hope its kinda clear :S

Thanks Alot

**UPDATE**

Thanks to vklidu i can now move my world to imitate the camera movement !
I would now need to do the same with the rotation.

[image]

**UPDATE 2 (SOLUTION)**

I was able to get it work by baking the copy location of the null of all objects to keyframe and then adding a null at the world origin that is acting as a parent of the objects null and then used a copy location on this origin null to the one on the path and i got the desired effect.

[image]

Comment: The whole point of this is to send the final animation to spark AR and inside spark ar no camera rotation is possible so it needs to be all bakes inside the object animations :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Object Constraint **Follow Path** for Camera
- Object Constraint **Copy Z Rotation** for Camera.001
- Object Constraint **Copy Location** for Mesh objects in negative

[image]
[image]
[image]

Bright orange Camera is active for rendering.
Camera on path can be any object. Mesh Objects are parented to Empty.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Ok this is so close to what i need, would there also be a way to add rotation of the camera to the mesh objects ? So my camera stays at 0,0,0 and rotation 0,0,0 and the world is moving and rotating ? Thanks Again

Comment: i updated the question with the progress @vklidu

Comment: Got it to work, i baked the copy location to keyframe and added a null at origin of the world and made the baked mesh null a children of it and then used a copy rotation modifer to the null on the path. ! Anyway thanks hahaha

Comment: great you found a solution, I wanted to find something interactive, but I messed up with armature, like you know since object is moving you need pivot point for rotation at world center. I tried to use Pivot Constraint, but it didnt work in this hierarchy, but there has to be a way with drivers or armature ... grrr. You need someone smarter ...

Comment: I played with the pivot constraint also with no good results ! Your smart enough i found a solution because of you ! Its no big deal that a part of it is baked. Thanks Again.

Answer (score 0):

Select all objects except the camera, making sure to select the plain last. Then parent all objects (except camera) to the plain. Now you only have to move the plain and everything else will move along with it except the camera which will remain at the origin.

NB I say to connect to the plain as this is visually obvious, however you could connect everything to an empty or any other object.

Comment: This part is not the issue i can parent everything to a null and more the null but i want to do it using the path for the camera if i parent all to all null and animate along the same path i dont get the desired effect.